# Percentage on pie chart label with multiple measures Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a pie chart with 2 measures  Current and Target
I have created a pie chart using these measures and am showing the values on the pie chart.

It's quite straightforward to build a pie chart with this setup, but I can't figure how to get the percentage (of total pie) to display on the label. Analysis->Percentage of->etc. gives me 100%, because it's only computed on one measure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB4Tu.png)

Can you please advise on how this can be done.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please include a little more details, like screenshot, etc.

Comment: I have a pie chart where I am having 2 measures current and target.I am showing sum in lables.Now I need to show % also along with sum.I just attached is the output image in main questiion.I am able to show only sum for now and need to show % also.

Comment: Please upload a complete snapshot showing, rows/columns shelf and marks card, at least.  Believe me, nothing is that impossible in Tableau given that the scenario you are having is properly conveyed.